# Search Auto Suggestion is not working

Tags: autocomplete

[image]

[image]

The error is coming from `form-mini.js`. I used two search boxes in  my theme. they are conflicting so i changed their id. but problem is the auto suggestion is not working. It is enabled from back-end but still not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the code with this module, this will help you to overcome with the search suggestion problem.

Please refer this Link - [Click Here](https://webkul.com/blog/replace-magento2-default-search-suggestion-logic/)

Hope this will help You!!